# Findbugs marker still displays after fixing issue

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

I have a project in eclipse and recently ran findbugs on it. Fixing a trivial issue and running findbugs on that class again does not get rid of the bug marker on the left hand side. In Findbugs perspective, I can also see that the overall findbugs count doesnt decrease aftrer making the necessary change.
[image]

The marker displays on the original line containing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried "clear bug markers"?

Comment: I got it working now. I wasnt building the project with the default java builder which outputs compiles the source into build/classes/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Findbugs bases its results on the analysis of the build folder produced by the default eclipse java builder. My project was compiling with a custom ant builder and therefore any changes to the source code were not picked up by the findbugs tool.